# Compile MySQL from source with OpenSSL on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, compilation, cmake, openssl

I'm trying to compile MySQL Community Server 5.7.17 from source with OpenSSL.  Based on my research this is the only way to use OpenSSL with MySQL unless you purchase the Enterprise Edition otherwise they use yaSSL instead of OpenSSL. (See first few lines here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/openssl-versus-yassl.html)

What I've done:  Downloaded the MySQL source for Windows, download/install OpenSSL for Windows, ran cmake gui against the source and specified `WITH_SSL=C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin` which is the path to OpenSSL on my build.

Here is a picture of my CMAKE GUI Error:

[CMAKE Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Bi7.jpg)

For some reason it's not identifying OpenSSL on my build I've been messing around for hours trying to get it to work and have gotten a bit further as this is the only error I have left.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Notes on my specific build:

- Windows 10 pro 64bit
- Using Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 as the Generator

**UPDATE: 03/23/2017**
Downloaded full version of OpenSSL (was using light) and changed path To C:/OpenSSL-Win64/ , it now identifies OpenSSL on the system but still can not find the openssl and crypto libraries.  There is a lib directoy under OpenSS-Win64 that seems to have openssl.lib and libcrypto.lib but not sure why the system isn't identifying them.

Comment: `WITH_SSL=C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin` is likely not correct. `bin/` is for binary files like the `openssl` program` and the DLLs. You likely need `WITH_SSL=C:/OpenSSL-Win64/`; but that's assuming there's a `C:/OpenSSL-Win64/include` and `C:/OpenSSL-Win64/lib` present.

Comment: Ok, so I had the light version of OpenSSL which did not have the libraries so I went back and downloaded the full version and changed the path which helped but I'm still getting errors.  It now identifies OpenSSL but says it can't find the appropriate system libraries for SSL. I updated the image above and it should contain the new error.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the MySQL source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/cmake/ssl.cmake#L87), it looks for

```
<value of WITH_SSL>/include/openssl/ssl.h
```

So, you probably need to set WITH_SSL to

```
C:/OpenSSL-Win64/
```

Comment: Ok, so I had the light version of OpenSSL which did not have the libraries so I went back and downloaded the full version and changed the path which helped but I'm still getting errors. It now identifies OpenSSL but says it can't find the appropriate system libraries for SSL. I updated the image above and it should contain the new error.

Comment: Just set `OPENSSL_LIBRARY` and `CRYPTO_LIBRARY` to point to the full paths to the libraries.  You may have to check the advanced box to be able to see these entries.

Comment: Even when checking the advanced box I do not see any option to set the paths for these libraries.

Comment: Just press the "Add Entry" button